# How to add a google map in laravel application, and show the nearest store to the user's local adress

Tags: laravel, google-maps

I'm using Laravel 5.7 framework, and I want to add google map interface to the store's register page to add their adress and save them in the database.
Then I want to compare the user's adress to the store's adress and show the nearest stores (1 or 2km).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can & Laravel is a great choice!

I would first build the register page and make sure you store the address in a way that's complete, so you can retrieve the Latitude & Longitude from the address(Easier to plot on the map, without converting the address each time using the google API).

I don't know your frontend level/interest, but using Vue.js or at least the javascript API is the way I would go for displaying the map.

You can use this part of the google API:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geometry#spherical.computeDistanceBetween

Based on that calculation you can retrieve and show the top nearest shops from the database.